# Image appears, and disappears

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a JS photo gallery, and the image that is supposed to be hidden, appears and disappears within page load. The awkward thing is, it's fine on Chrome, it's just that firefox does this. I tried hiding the overflow but this didn't work either:

`<div class="Grid_4  fr" style="overflow: hidden;">`

The above code is a div which contains the gallery.

Every image in the gallery is specified using the following code...

```
<li jcarouselindex="1" class="jc-item jc-item-hor jc-item-1 jc-item-1-hor">
    <a href="#" class="newsThumb">
        <img src="#" width="324" height="182">
    </a>
    <div class="vBgTitle noeffect">
        <div class="vTitle innerText">Text here</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: It seems to be happening after I pass number 3 on jcarouselindex. i.e if more than `<li jcarouselindex="3"...`, it does that. It's fine if it's three and less.